# Getting issue while creating dataframe with specific datatype in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Data from SampleCSV2.csv is as follows:

```
AAA|25|IT|50.5
BBB|28|Comp|100.5
```

Getting issue while creating dataframe with specific datatype in pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType, DateType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.types import * 

def structSchema(cols):
    field = []
    for c in cols:
        fieldType = c[c.find(":")+1:]
        fieldName = c[:c.find(":")]
        print(fieldType,"P",fieldName)
        if fieldType == "int":
            field.append(StructField(fieldName, IntegerType(), True))
        elif fieldType == "double":
            field.append(StructField(fieldName, DoubleType(), True))
        else :
            field.append(StructField(fieldName, StringType(), True))
    return StructType(field)

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('OutputGenerator')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
file =r'C:\Users\Desktop\SampleCSV2.csv'

delim = '|'

#This part works well
cols = ['Name:string','Age:string','Dept:string','Salary:string']
rdd = sc.textFile(file).map(lambda x: x.split(delim))
cols = structSchema(cols)
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=cols)
print(df1.toPandas()) #works fine


#Getting error while executing below part
cols = ['Name:string','Age:int','Dept:string','Salary:double']
rdd = sc.textFile(file).map(lambda x: x.split(delim))
cols = structSchema(cols)
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=cols)
print(df2.toPandas())  #Getting Error

print("Done...")
```

Getting error to the line `print(df2.toPandas())` Please help me with defining schema and loading csv to dataframe with specific datatype. Schema definition works when all columns are of stringType(), but fails when I define type like Integer, Double.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `csv` reader:

```
spark.read.schema(cols).options(delimiter="|", header="false").csv(file)
```

Your code won't work because schema doesn't match the data. You have to case values to declared types:

```
sc.textFile(file).map(lambda x: x.split(delim)).map(lambda x: (
    (x[0], int(x[1]), x[2], float(x[3]))
))
```